# NullReferenceException on creating an instance of an inheriting class

Tags: c#, mono, monogame

I am writing my own game engine in XNA and started to port it into MonoGame so that I can put it on Android/iOS/Windows 8. For some reason I am getting a null reference exception when the main create a new game object. So the code that allocates the object is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //game g = new game();
        using (game game = new game())
        {
            game.Run();
        }
    }
```

and the error is as

```
    public lesaEngine()
```

which is the base constructor for the game object.

the inheritance is just as always

```
    class lesaEngine : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    class game : lesaEngine
```

Not sure whats going on here. It works normally under normal XNA. I am using Visual Studio 2012 for the port.

Comment: Is the NRE occurring at the `game.Run()` call, or is it being thrown by the constructor called in the `new game()` expression?  If the error is being thrown in the `lesaEngine()` constructor, can you post the body of that constructor?

Comment: In addition to what @phoog has said, constructors are not inherited so your game constructor must call the lesaEngine constructor, if needed.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway if a derived class's constructor doesn't explicitly call another constructor, then it will implicitly call the base class's default constructor.  If there's no default constructor in the base class, or if it is not accessible, the code will not compile.

Comment: To rephrase my first comment: can you post the stack trace of the NullReferenceException?

Comment: So just to clarify, the above code compiles and runs under XNA on Windows? But now you are compiling and running that same code under what? iOS, Android, Windows 8?

Comment: I am using Windows 8. It is a MonoGame project. It runs and compiles just fine under the normal Windows Environment.

Comment: Did you create a new Win8 monogame project? if so the entry point should look more like this #if !NETFX_CORE
   using (MyGame game = new MyGame())
   {
    game.Run();
   }
#endif
#if  NETFX_CORE
   var factory = new MonoGame.Framework.GameFrameworkViewSource<MyGame>();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.Run(factory);
#endif
        }

Comment: @Miau that looks like an answer.  Why don't you put it in the answer box?

Comment: I thought that maybe it was too obvious but ... yes I guess

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a new Win8 monogame project? if so the entry point should look more like this

```
#if !NETFX_CORE 
  using (MyGame game = new MyGame()) 
  { 
      game.Run();
  } 
#endif 
#if NETFX_CORE 
  var factory = newMonoGame.Framework.GameFrameworkViewSource<MyGame>();
  Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.Run(factory); 
#endif }
```